# Uniform density 2d peak detection of spectrogram

Tags: matlab, spectrogram, music, peak-detection, sound-recognition

I am trying to recreate the algorithm used by Shazam to recognize music, as outlined in the paper [An Industrial-Strength Audio Search Algorithm](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Edpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf).  The algorithm performs a specialized peak detection to a spectrogram in order to recognize songs.  The developers give the following details about the peak detection.

> A time-frequency point is a candidate peak if it has a
> higher energy content than all its neighbors in a region
> centered around the point. Candidate peaks are chosen
> according to a density criterion in order to assure that the
> time-frequency strip for the audio file has reasonably
> uniform coverage. The peaks in each time-frequency
> locality are also chosen according amplitude, with the
> justification that the highest amplitude peaks are most
> likely to survive the distortions listed above.

Based on this description, I am trying to find a peak detection model that will provide non-neighboring, relatively uniformly distributed peaks.  The best approach I have tried so far is CFAR peak detection, but this technique tends to create clusters of neighboring peaks.  I would appreciate other suggestions for this application.

Answer (score 2):

What about an heuristic?

A 1D version of the algorithm that runs in $O(n \, log(w))$ iterations, where `w` is the size of the neighborhood considered can be obtained by successively keeping a list of peaks, and each iteration compare select the highest of three consecutive peaks, to make it more efficient you can decimate the peaks and get a faster algorithm.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
x = np.random.rand(512)
r = np.arange(len(x))
for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(611+i);
    plt.stem(r, x[r]);plt.xticks([]);
    # take the best of 3 peaks, and decimate by a factor of 2
    
    r = np.where(x[r[1:-1:2]] > x[r[:-2:2]], 
                 np.where(x[r[2::2]] > x[r[1:-1:2]], 
                          r[2::2], r[1:-1:2]), r[:-2:2]);
    
    plt.stem(r, x[r], '-r');
```

[image]

And you can easily generalize this to 2D, e.g. doing one iteration on the vertical axis followed by one iteration on the horizontal axis.